# Form Validation - Replace Blank Fields

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have several tables, with form elements - all of these elements are submitted as a single form and parsed.  I would like to add some validation, using jQuery for the .submit() parameters.

I have found some code online, but these produce error messages, I was wondering if anyone knows of any sample code that can perform the following:

```
On .submit()
if textBox1 = ""
    then replace empty textBox1 with "1"
else if textBox2 = ""
    then replace empty textBox2 with "-1"
and continue to submit the form
```

Comment: Sorry, bad phrasing - replace the blank text box with a "1" or "-1" as the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pseudo-code translated precisely:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($('input[name="textBox1"]').val() == "") {
        $('input[name="textBox1"]').val("1");
    } elseif ($('input[name="textBox2"]') == "") {
        $('input[name="textBox2"]').val("-1");
    }
});
```

EDIT:

If, for whatever reason, you need to duplicate the `name` attribute across multiple inputs, you can target inputs by the `id` attribute instead:

```
// HTML form
<input type="text" name="textBox1" id="foo" />
<input type="text" name="textBox1" id="bar" />

// Javascript
$("form").submit(function() {
    if ($('input[id="foo"]').val() == "") {
        $('input[id="foo"]').val("1");
    } elseif ($('input[id="bar"]') == "") {
        $('input[id="bar"]').val("-1");
    }
});
```

Comment: This assumes your form inputs are named accordingly, e.g., `<input type="text" name="textBox1" /> <input type="text" name="textBox2" />`.

Comment: I'm attempting to implement this - does it change it much if there are a server of textboxes called textBox1 and textBox2?

Comment: Do you mean that more than one input shares the name `textBox1` (or `textBox2`)? Not sure why you'd want to do that... inputs are typically identified by their `name` attribute, so if you had duplicate names, you'd get duplicate values passed from the form.

Answer (score 1):

```
var textBoxDefaultValues = {
    textBox1 : '1',
    textBox2 : '-1' 
};

$(formSelector).on('submit', function () {
    $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val(textBoxDefaultValues[$(this).attr('name')]);
        }
    });
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Two questions: should '$(formSelector)' be the ID of my form?  Also should 'attr('name')' be value...?  As its the contents of the textbox that I want to update?

Comment: 1. Any css selector for your form (example 'form#my-form'), or reference to form's DOM element (example, document.forms[0])

Comment: 2. Name - is an attribute of form elements. For example <input type="text" name="textBox1" />

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  if $(this).find("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    if $(this).val() == "") $(this).val("1");
    if $(this).val() == "..") $(this).val("-1");
  });
});
```

This solution might be more straightfoward/simpler to understand. If you have a lot of inputs Atber's solution will probably be more fitting.

Comment: Can your code be replaced as such?
`if $(".textBox1").val() == "") $(".textBox1").val("1");`
`if $(".textBox2").val() == "..") $(".textBox2").val("-1");`

Comment: Try and describe what your problem is now, and I can help.

Comment: I'm just wondering if there the close bracket after the == "" is a mistake or not..?

Comment: Also, I have a series of textboxes called textBox1 and textBox2 - does that change the code?